# Test fails with parent mock class

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have `DetailViewModel` and CoreDetailViewModel` and DetailViewModel is extending CoreDetailViewModel

```
class DetailViewModel @Inject constructor(xxxapp: XXXApp) : CoreDetailViewModel(xxxapp), Injectable


abstract class CoreDetailViewModel(val context: Application) : AndroidViewModel(context){

  private val liveEventActionTitleMutableData = MutableLiveData<String>()
  val liveEventActionTitleData: LiveData<String>
    get() = liveEventActionTitleMutableData
}
```

in my test class I mock `DetailViewModel` and

`````
viewModel = Mockito.mock(DetailViewModel::class.java)
 Mockito.`when`(viewModel.liveEventActionTitleData).thenReturn(data)````

and my test fails saying
`````

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
    when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
    For example:
        when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

````
Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.```
````

as soon as I move liveEventActionTitleData to DetailViewModel it works 
I am wondering why if CoreDetailViewModel is abstract ?